# Cleaner notation for cardinality of set instead of |{⋅}|

Tags: notation

I feel it's a little ugly to use the normal "absolute value" notation for the size of an anonymous set-builder set:

$$
N = |\{ x \in \mathcal{X} : f(x) \geq 0 \}|
$$

Is there a preferred replacement? I feel like I've seen

$$
N = \# \{ x \in \mathcal{X} : f(x) \geq 0 \}
$$

in some informal notes, but I'm not sure if it's used in formal publications.

Comment: I've used $\#\{ \ \}$ notation in a paper that was published in Applied and Computational Harmonic Analysis. So it definitely can be used in a formal publication.

Comment: Since the number of elements in a set is called the cardinality of the set, maybe writing $\operatorname{card} A$ is a good idea?

Comment: I agree that using the "absolute value" bars is a bad notation. I use $\#$ myself.

Comment: I had never seen the $\#\{\}$ notation until I moved to the United States. It puzzled me at first, then I really hated it and it drove me nuts, ... and by now I use it myself. So it may be a North American or an English-based thing. Although it's probably been picking up in popularity around the world now. Still, it feels to me that "$\#\{\}$" is mostly used as the number of items when we can count them, i.e. for finite sets. I don't think I've ever seen it to represent the cardinality of an arbitrary set.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the "size" of set is not well-defined.  "Size" could refer to any of a plethora of different things, such as cardinality, measure, or diameter.  If you mean "cardinality" (which seems to be the intended meaning, based on the the use of $\#\{x\in \mathcal{X} : f(x) \ge 0\}$), then you should say "cardinality", and not "size".

Assuming that cardinality *is* the meaning of the notation, then there are several notations which I have seen in the wild (in publications, on the interwebs, etc.):

- $\operatorname{card}(A)$ (this is the notation I prefer)
- $|A|$
- $\#A$
- $\mathcal{N}(A)$
- $n(A)$
- $\bar{\bar{A}}$

The notations higher on the list are, I think, somewhat more universal, and more likely to be understood from context.  I would still recommend taking the space to explicitly explain the notation (e.g. "The cardinality of a set $A$ is denoted by $\#A$").

Regarding the use of these notations in formal publication, that is between you and your editor (and/or reviewers).  Pick whichever notation you prefer, and change it if you are asked to by an editor or reviewer.

Comment: Good point, edited. I did mean cardinality.